# Is Fano Kahler surface with reverse orientation also Kahler?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

In particular, do Fano Kahler surfaces with reverse orientation admit Kahler-Einstein metrics?

Comment: By a result of Kotschick, a compact complex surface which admits a complex structure for the reverse orientation has signature $0$. For Fano (= Del Pezzo) surfaces, this happens only for $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$, in which case you can conclude by yourself.